# iMessage extension Tapping same message twice doesn't call didSelectMessage

Tags: imessage

When a user taps a message in iMessages,

The call:

-(void)didSelectMessage:(MSMessage *)message conversation:(MSConversation *)conversation

is correctly dispatched. However, this doesn't get dispatched a second time. Does anyone know if this is expected behavior or how to get around this?